# Trigonometric Polynomials Satisfying Certain Conditions

Tags: trigonometry

A *trigonometric polynomial* is defined (at least for this question) as a finite linear combination of functions $\sin(a_i x)$ and $\cos(b_j x)$ with $a_i, b_j \in \mathbb{R}$. I'm asking if there is some trigonometric polynomial $f(x)$ where for defined $c, \, n >0, \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(0)=c$, and for some $b \in (0,1]$, $|f(x)|\leq 1, x \in [b,n]$. The period of $f(x)$ should be $n$, so $\max |a_i|=\frac{\pi}n$ and $\max |b_j|=\frac{\pi}{2n}$.

Answer (score 0):

The "closest" trigonometric polynomial turns out to be the truncated Fourier series. Look up the relevant theory.gb

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but it's not guaranteed that $\max |a_i|=\frac{\pi}n$ and $\max |b_j|=\frac{\pi}{2n}$, as stipulated in the question above.